# call a stored procedure with more than one result sets into another procedure and work with them

Tags: stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that have 2 result sets and I want to call this sp into another stored procedure and get both it’s result sets and work with them. I have searched in Internet and Knew about the new fearture in sql server 2012 for this purpose. It is ‘RESULT SETS’.

Except using ‘Result sets’, is there another solution for call storedprocedure with more than one resultset into another procedure and work with them?

Pinal Dave has an example for using ‘Result Sets’

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE mySP1 (@ShiftID INT, @JobCandidateID INT)
AS

-- ResultSet 1

SELECT [ShiftID],[Name],[StartTime],[EndTime],[ModifiedDate]
FROM   [HumanResources].[Shift]
WHERE  [ShiftID] = @ShiftID

-- ResultSet 2

SELECT [JobCandidateID],[BusinessEntityID],[ModifiedDate]
FROM [HumanResources].[JobCandidate]
WHERE JobCandidateID = @JobCandidateID

CREATE PROCEDURE mySP2
AS
EXEC mySP1 @ShiftID = 2, @JobCandidateID = 5

WITH RESULT SETS
( ( [ShiftID] TINYINT,[Name] NVARCHAR(50),[StartTime] DATETIME,       [EndTime] DATETIME,[UpdateDate] DATETIME -- Notice Name Change
 ),([JobCandidateID] INT,[BusinessEntityID] INT,[ModifiedDate] DATETIME ));
```

When we use the Result Set, we have the mysp1 results into these:

For ResultSet1:

```
[ShiftID] TINYINT,[Name] NVARCHAR(50),[StartTime] DATETIME,
[EndTime] DATETIME,[UpdateDate] DATETIME
```

And for Resultset2:

```
[JobCandidateID] INT,[BusinessEntityID] INT,[ModifiedDate] DATETIME
```

But now I want to query on these results in mySp2. How can I do this.
How can I select the values from :

```
[ShiftID] TINYINT,[Name] NVARCHAR(50),[StartTime] DATETIME
,[EndTime] DATETIME,[UpdateDate] DATETIME
```

And

```
[JobCandidateID] INT,[BusinessEntityID] INT,[ModifiedDate] DATETIME
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution may be using output variables in mySP1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mySP1 (
@ShiftID INT
, @JobCandidateID INT
, @CUR1 CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
)
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @CUR1 = CURSOR
FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
    SELECT [ShiftID],[Name],[StartTime],[EndTime],[ModifiedDate]
    FROM   [HumanResources].[Shift]
    WHERE  [ShiftID] = @ShiftID

OPEN @CUR1;
GO
```

to calling this sp:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
EXEC dbo.mySP1 @ShiftID = 1, @JobCandidateID = 1, @CUR1 = @MyCursor OUTPUT;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN;
     FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor;
END;
CLOSE @MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
```

Use a combination of this with a standar output or just declare another cursor output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the cursor has no good performance. Both of my first sp result sets have many records and if I use cursor to get them, My performance will be so bad.

Comment: The solution is valid but is not what you want. 
You could specify that :). 
In your example you have two very simple selects.
Why not to split them in two diferent SP ?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, The sample above is the Pinal Dave's sample not my sp. I have to return two result sets in one sp because most of their scenario is in common between them. both of my result sets have many records and if I use Cursor the performance will be so bad.